# How can i get the url of a website with powershell and look all the links of this page ( crawl)

Tags: powershell, web-crawler

Hi I`m trying to make a spider crawl in powershell. 
it make a list of all the urls in a web and for each url it look all the urls and so on according to depth

I have this

```
Function Get-DepthURL ($url, $depth){
$count = 0
Write-Host “URL”  $url
$Test = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url
[int]$top=[int]$depth
$link=$Test.Links | Foreach {$_.href 
    if ($top -ne 0){
    [int]$top=[int]$top-[int]1
Get-DepthURL ("$link", $top)
}
$count = [int]$count+[int]1
}
Write-Host “Number of Hrefs on URL=”  $count
}
```

the problem is when i try to recursivly in on another url

```
Get-DepthURL ("$link", $top)
```

the variable $link get the entire web and i want just the url that i am looking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues with the script as it stands.

Firstly lets make it work as the looping logic is not going to work like this. Also it would be clearer to analyse what is going on if you created an extra function and used the foreach as an iterator rather than in a pipe (it will also allow you to use better console logging):

```
function Process-Link([string]$link, [int] $depth){
    write-host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta $depth $link
    $result = [System.uri]$link

    if ($result.IsAbsoluteUri -and $depth -ge 0){
        [int]$depth--
        Get-DepthURL $link $depth
    }
}

Function Get-DepthURL ([string]$url, [int]$depth){    
    $Test = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan “$depth Found " $Test.Links.Count " Links in URL $url"
    $Test.Links | foreach { $_.href }

    foreach($link in $Test.Links){ 
        Process-Link $link.href $depth
    }
}

#Get-DepthURL "http://foldingair.blogspot.com" 1 
Get-DepthURL "https://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~rodham/cs240/crawler/index.html" 1
```

Don't underestimate how fast and wide your crawl will get, even with the very simple URL with only 9 links will soon become a very large crawl.

### Other issues (which I've not fixed)

If there are any circular references they will all be followed round in a circle forever, i would hazard a guess that the pages you are crawling have circular references, most websites do.

Relative links will not resolve correctly and so will throw errors, and in your original code will cause strange things to happen in your loop.

Finally remember that the links can be to any resources on the web (images, javascript, movies) and the links might be dynamic in nature and wired up via javascript.